# How to get System.ServiceModel.DiscoveryClient to use IGMP?

Tags: c#, igmp

I have a D-Link DGS-1210-10P with two VLAN's (10.104.*.* and 192.168.*.*)  I have a video camera on each network, and two NIC's in my computer on each network.

With IGMP off on the D-Link, I can discover both cameras using Microsoft DiscoveryClient, and some custom endpoint that allows me to specify which NIC to send the mutlicast message out.  With IGMP turned on, I only see the 10.104 network.

```
foreach (string id in getAdapterIds())
{
   DiscoveryClient dc = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpointByNIC(DiscoveryVersion.WSDiscoveryApril2005, id));
   dc.FindProgressChanged += _real_FindProgressChanged;
   dc.FindAsync();
}
```

I do see IGMP messages in Wireshark (both sources are my computer, and the destination is the correct multicast address)

```
Source        Destination     Protocol Length Info
10.104.128.37 239.255.255.250 IGMPv2   60     Membership Report Group
192.168.1.1   239.255.255.250 IGMPv2   60     Membership Report Group
```

My question boils down to: Does DiscoveryClient automatically join IGMP groups and should just work?  I'm suspecting that there is just some fundamental IGMP understanding I'm missing, or some D-Link router setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, I find answers right after I ask questions:

The problem was that IGMP on the router was not set up correctly.

So,

**Corporate VLAN**

1) Disable "Querier State", because the corporate switch is already a querier

2) Enable "Fast Leave"

**Isolated VLAN**

1) Enable "Querier State", [because each VLAN needs a querier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IGMP_snooping#IGMP_querier)

2) Enable "Fast Leave"